# My stored procedure executes several times?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I wrote a stored procedure that filters my table. It is working fine, and selects the correct records, but in the result for example if query have to return one record.

Instead of one record return too many record is it possible my stored procedure executes several times?

I use this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[propertyFilterByCity] 
    @city NVARCHAR(150) = NULL,
    @DefaultPageIndex smallint = NULL,
    @DefaultPageSize smallint = NULL,
    @RecordCount bit = NULL,
    @MinPrice decimal(18, 0) = NULL,
    @MaxPrice decimal(18, 0) = NULL,
    @bedRoom smallint = NULL,
    @PropertyType NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @requestType NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @Parking bit = NULL,
    @RemoteParking bit = NULL,
    @Lobby bit = NULL,
    @AssemblyHall bit = NULL,
    @Gym bit = NULL,
    @Surveillance bit = NULL,
    @FireAlarm bit = NULL,
    @FireFighting bit = NULL,
    @Pool bit = NULL,
    @Sauna bit = NULL,
    @Jacuzzi bit = NULL,
    @Carwash bit = NULL,
    @Laundry bit = NULL,
    @Custodian bit = NULL,
    @Shooting bit = NULL,
    @TheftAlarm bit = NULL,
    @PanelFit bit = NULL,
    @Sentry bit = NULL,
    @CentralSatellite bit = NULL,
    @CentralAntenna bit = NULL,
    @Fireplaces bit = NULL,
    @MasterRoom bit = NULL,
    @Patio bit = NULL,
    @Barbecue bit = NULL,
    @UPS bit = NULL,
    @RoofGarden bit = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON ;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        DECLARE @CityId int;
        IF EXISTS(SELECT Estate_CityId FROM [^Estate_City] WHERE Estate_CityName = @city)
            BEGIN
                SET @CityId= (SELECT Estate_CityId FROM [^Estate_City] WHERE Estate_CityName = @city);
            END
        IF(@MinPrice IS NOT NULL AND @MaxPrice IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN       
            IF (@MaxPrice>0 AND @MaxPrice>@MinPrice)
            BEGIN           
                DECLARE @results TABLE (RowNum INT,Estate_Code BIGINT,Estate_propertyType NVARCHAR(50),Estate_buildingArea NVARCHAR(20),Estate_floor NVARCHAR(10),Estate_neighborhoodProperty NVARCHAR(100),Estate_street1 NVARCHAR(100),
                Estate_street2 NVARCHAR(100),Estate_visits BIGINT,houseImage NVARCHAR(MAX),houseImage1 NVARCHAR(MAX),houseImage2 NVARCHAR(MAX),houseImage3 NVARCHAR(MAX),houseImage4 NVARCHAR(MAX),Owner_requestType NVARCHAR(MAX),
                Facility_Description NVARCHAR(MAX),Estate_BedRoomCount NVARCHAR(2))
                INSERT INTO @results(RowNum,Estate_Code,Estate_propertyType,Estate_buildingArea,Estate_floor,Estate_neighborhoodProperty,Estate_street1,Estate_street2,Estate_visits,houseImage,houseImage1,
                houseImage2,houseImage3,houseImage4,Owner_requestType,Facility_Description,Estate_BedRoomCount)
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [^Estate].Estate_Code) AS [Row],[^Estate].Estate_Code,[^Estate].Estate_propertyType, [^Estate].Estate_buildingArea,[^Estate].Estate_floor,[^Estate].Estate_neighborhoodProperty,[^Estate].Estate_street1,[^Estate].Estate_street2,[^Estate].Estate_visits,[^Estate_Images].houseImage,[^Estate_Images].houseImage1,[^Estate_Images].houseImage2,[^Estate_Images].houseImage3,[^Estate_Images].houseImage4,[^Estate_OwnerInfo].RequestType_Type,[^Estate_Facility].Facility_descText,[^Estate].Estate_bedRoomCount
                FROM [^Estate]
                INNER JOIN [^Estate_Images] ON [^Estate].Estate_Code=[^Estate_Images].Estate_Code
                INNER JOIN [^Estate_OwnerInfo] ON [^Estate].Owner_code=[^Estate_OwnerInfo].Owner_code
                INNER JOIN [^Estate_Facility] ON [^Estate].Estate_Code=[^Estate_Facility].Estate_Code
                INNER JOIN [^Estate_City] ON [^Estate].Estate_CityId =[^Estate].Estate_CityId
                WHERE 
                    (@CityId IS NULL OR [^Estate].Estate_CityId =@CityId ) AND
                    (@requestType IS NULL OR [^Estate_OwnerInfo].RequestType_Type = @requestType) AND
                    ([^Estate].Estate_totalPrice BETWEEN @MinPrice AND @MaxPrice) AND
                    (@bedRoom IS NULL OR [^Estate].Estate_bedRoomCount>@bedRoom) AND
                    (@PropertyType IS NULL OR [^Estate].Estate_propertyType = @PropertyType) AND
                    (@requestType IS NULL OR [^Estate_OwnerInfo].RequestType_Type = @requestType) AND
                    (@bedRoom IS NULL OR [^Estate].Estate_bedRoomCount = @bedRoom) AND
                    (@Parking IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Parking = @Parking) AND
                    (@RemoteParking IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_RemoteParking = @RemoteParking) AND
                    (@Lobby IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Lobby = @Lobby)AND
                    (@Gym IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Gym = @Gym) AND
                    (@Surveillance IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Surveillance = @Surveillance) AND
                    (@FireAlarm IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_FireAlarm = @FireAlarm) AND
                    (@FireFighting IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_FireFighting = @FireFighting) AND
                    (@Pool IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Pool = @Pool) AND
                    (@Sauna IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Sauna = @Sauna) AND
                    (@Jacuzzi IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Jacuzzi = @Jacuzzi) AND
                    (@Carwash IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Carwash = @Carwash) AND
                    (@Laundry IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Laundry = @Laundry) AND
                    (@Custodian IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Custodian = @Custodian) AND
                    (@Shooting IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Shooting = @Shooting) AND
                    (@TheftAlarm IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_TheftAlarm = @TheftAlarm) AND
                    (@PanelFit IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_PanelFit = @PanelFit) AND
                    (@Sentry IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Sentry = @Sentry) AND
                    (@CentralSatellite IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_CentralSatellite = @CentralSatellite) AND
                    (@CentralAntenna IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_CentralAntenna = @CentralAntenna) AND
                    (@Fireplaces IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Fireplaces = @Fireplaces) AND
                    (@MasterRoom IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_MasterRoom = @MasterRoom) AND
                    (@Patio IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Patio = @Patio) AND
                    (@Barbecue IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_Barbecue = @Barbecue) AND
                    (@UPS IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_UPS= @UPS) AND
                    (@RoofGarden IS NULL OR [^Estate_Facility].Facility_RoofGarden = @RoofGarden)
            END
        END
        select * from @results order by Estate_Code;
        DECLARE @ErrorCode INT;
            DECLARE @Result INT;
            SET @ErrorCode = @@ERROR;
            IF (@ErrorCode <> 0)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                SET @Result=0;
                EXEC Debug_InsertSQLErrorDetails
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
                SET @Result=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
            END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;   
        END
        EXEC Debug_InsertSQLErrorDetails
        SET @Result=0;
    END CATCH
END
```

Please help me to solve this problem thanks!

Comment: It is not possible. Probably your select for some data return more than 1 row.

Comment: What type of naming convention is to start every table name with `^`?

Comment: Second thing which concerns me `SET @CityId= (SELECT Estate_CityId FROM [^Estate_City] WHERE Estate_CityName = @city);` Are you sure that you won't get multiple cities with the same name?

Comment: Is using transaction for data read your requirement?

Comment: Why do you insert  data to table variable only to select them further?

Comment: I have to say I suspect you get poor performance too, unless your dataset is small. You can write it a lot better.

Comment: You should check following query: 
 `select * from @results order by Estate_Code;`
It may return more than one record as you are inserting data from different tables and all the data inserted in `@result` table will be return as you have `select statement` in your `stored procedure`.

Comment: So it is not entire SP? Where the paging is done (DB/Application)?

Comment: So you didn't post entire stored procedure, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a stored procedure will not run multiple times.

The reason could be thatfrom the Estate table you join multiple tables. If these joins are not 1 to 1, but 1 to n, you'll get a result row for each possible join.

Eg, if an Estate has multiple images, you'll get a row for each estate image in your result.